# C# ODBC Driver working fine on Win10 but not Win7

Tags: c#, windows-7, odbc, paradox

I got a Problem with an old ODBC Driver for Paradox Database (Intersolv ODBC Paradox Driver). I have an application to read and write data to a Paradox database while the Main Program of the Databases is running. I have got Problems before with the MS Paradox Driver. Now with this driver everything works fine and I can work simultaneously on the Database. My Problem is this only works with Windows 10. With Win7 I get an Error when trying to open the Database (SQLAllocHandle error). If I close the Main Program the driver works. I tried to access the Database with a Windows Service and that works  on Win7 I can access the Data while the Main Program is open.

I tried opening the Application with Adminrights and start it with Psexec System acc. Always the same error when Main Program is open. Does anyone know whats the difference there between Win7 and Win10? Both 64 Bit.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact same problem on a 64 bit system, trying to open a Paradox table to read data while the original Delphi application also was running.  Using the Microsoft Paradox driver I would get the "External table is not in expected format" error when I tried to execute my ODBC DataReader, and if I used the Intersolv driver, it would give the same SQLAllocHandle error that you are seeing when I tried to open the connection.

I found in the comments of this thread:

[Paradox Table - Oledb Exception: External table is not in the expected format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45858608/paradox-table-oledb-exception-external-table-is-not-in-the-expected-format)

that having the connection in a static object made the difference.  In my app, I moved the DB connection and query code to a static class and then it started working.  This could possibly be why the Windows service you mentioned was able to read your data.

I'm not sure as to why the difference between Win7 and Win10, but I suspect that it's a thread permissions issue when trying to open the PDOXUSRS.LCK file.

Hope this helps you.